# Sending HTTP Header Info with Java UrlConnection

Tags: java

Alright, so I have this bit of code, and when I make the request, I would like to include some HTTP Header info.  How would I go about doing that?

```
public boolean call(String apiCall) {
    if (this.apiCalls.containsKey(apiCall)) {
        try{
            URL url = this.apiCalls.get(apiCall);
            url = new URL(url.toString() + "?memberid=76710");

            URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

            InputStream is = urlConn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                baf.append((byte)current);
            }

            this.responseResultText = new String(baf.toByteArray());
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e){
            this.responseResultText = e.getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
    this.responseResultText = "API call " + apiCall + " doesn't exist.";
    return false;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`URLConnection#setRequestProperty()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
```

#### See also:

- [How to use `URLConnection`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)